# linq select field type unknown

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var query =
        from product in products.AsEnumerable()
        where product.Field<string>("Product") == "Phone"
        select new
        {
            Name = product.Field<string>("Name"),
            ProductNumber = product.Field<string>("ProductNumber"),
            ListPrice = product.Field<Decimal>("Price")
        };
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

I assume that's because in the `ProductNumber` column I don't always have  doesn't always have strings, and in the first row the `ProductNumber` is actually an `int`. I've tried converting and casting them to string, but didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `ProductNumber = product.Field<int>("ProductNumber").ToString(),`

Comment: Why won't you just change `string` to `int` (i.e. `product.Field<string>("ProductNumber"),` to `product.Field<int>("ProductNumber"),`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that until now and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @RoxanaDinca You are welcome. dasblinkenlight has provided answer with some nice explanation. I recommend to accept his/her answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `Field<T>`:

> `InvalidCastException` [is thrown when] the value type of the underlying column could not be cast to the type specified by the generic parameter, T.

It looks like in your case the column type is a nullable integer, so you need to do something like this:

```
var query =
    from product in products.AsEnumerable()
    where product.Field<string>("Product") == "Phone"
    select new
    {
        Name = product.Field<string>("Name"),
        // Below, I am using ""+... idiom for a null-safe ToString
        ProductNumber = ""+product.Field<int?>("ProductNumber"),
        ListPrice = product.Field<Decimal>("Price")
    };
```

The idea is to retrieve the value as an `int`, but accept data rows where the data is missing.

If you do not mind `ProductNumber` of your anonymous class being nullable `int`s instead of `string`s, remove the `""+` part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

First you fetch the records as enumerable with ProductNumber as string and then later on Enumerable have a conversion from string to int.